# Attach Local image in MMS in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I have one application in that I convert `UIView` in the image and send that file as an Email or an MMS. It is possible to send via Email using the `addAttachmentData` Method, but I can not find a similar solution for MMS.

Is there an MMS solution similar to the Email solution?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to attach photos to the MMS sheet currently. Right now it is only for the Email sheet.

Comment: it is possible or not that we can copy the content of view so that we can paste that content to native SMS application because i see one application cartolina card in that application it it possible that paste card in SMS application.