# alternative for MFMessageComposeViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I browsed around and saw that MFMessageComposeViewController doesn't support MMS, however some suggested using third party vendor to send MMS with photo attachments.

Someone know about a free vendor, or examples on using these mms email gateways on iOS devices with photo attachments?

I know how to send a text message using a the email gateway, but not a photo.

Also, anyone heard about a custom-made controller that uses those email gateways, that i can integrate into my app, in the same way i intrgrate MFMessageComposeViewController?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to attach Image with message via iPhone application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577565/how-to-attach-image-with-message-via-iphone-application)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to do this currently. The iPhone has no public API for sending MMS. Only way you can achieve this is to use a providers MMS gateway directly, but this would not work worldwide.
These three other stack overflow questions about MMS had the same conclusion:

[How can my app send MMS with a photo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262881/how-can-my-app-send-mms-with-a-photo)

[Attach Local image in MMS in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778680/attach-local-image-in-mms-in-iphone)

[For the current iphone version,  MMS is possible or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028542/for-the-current-iphone-version-mms-is-possible-or-not)

Answer (score 0):

To programmatically send an MMS, you have four options:

1. Use an email -> MMS gateway (e.g. 2125551234(at)vzwpix.com) - check out a full list of US email gateways at http://www.tipb.com/2009/01/09/i...
2. Use a GSM/GPRS/EDGE/CDMA modem to send/receive via the MM1 protocol.
3. Use a messaging aggregator such as mBlox, OpenMarket, etc or use a third party gateway who can abstract alot of the connection details such as Websnapme (www.websnapme.com).
4. Use a direct connection to a carrier and use the MM7 protocol.

Option 4 is pretty much impossible for most people/companies so you would need to explore options 1 to 3.